# Selenium - python - how to update the url of the current iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I try to script some test on an internal website in selenium in python.
And this site contains a lot of iframes.

I have no issue to switch iframe, but I try to set the url of the current iframe, and I do not find any method to attain this.

```
iframe1 = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'iframe1')))
driver.switch_to_frame  (iframe1)
iframe2 = WebDriverWait (driver, 10).until (EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'iframe2')))
driver.switch_to_frame  (iframe2)
# I was expecting something like this
driver.get("/new_url_inside_my_frame.html")
```

But it does not work, at first because get does not works with relative url, but even if I use a complete url, it sets the all the page and not just the iframe.

I am pretty sure, this is possible, I just not find how anywhere.

Comment: I can do this through js like this:


driver.execute_script       ("window.location.pathname = '/new_url_inside_my_frame.html'");

But I would have preferred another method

Comment: Haven't tried this but are iframes considered different handles?

Comment: seems not the case